# wordpress wrap each post in its own div

Tags: php, wordpress, html

I'd like to be able to style each WP post individually, and for the while post loop to automatically assign each new post to its own div.  For example:

```
<div id="blog-content-wp">
  <div class="post">
    Post 1
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    Post 2
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my code so far:

```
<div id="blog-content-wp">
<?php while(have_posts()): the_post()?>
  <?php $myposts = get_posts('');
    foreach($myposts as $post) :
    setup_postdata($post);
  ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>          
<?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endwhile;?>
<?php comments_template('', true);?>
</div>
```

All this does is put all of my posts inside blog-content-wp, and all I want to achieve is a separate div for each post.

Any suggestions?  I know this might be a duplicate, but so far all I've seen is "how to get three posts per div" etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

print out the new divs inside your loop, wrapped around your call to the_content()

```
<div id="blog-content-wp">
<?php while(have_posts()): the_post()?>
  <?php $myposts = get_posts('');
    foreach($myposts as $post) :
    setup_postdata($post);
  ?>

<div >
<?php the_content(); ?>          
</div >

<?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endwhile;?>
<?php comments_template('', true);?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it with post class, gives classes with tag, class and many more

```
  <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
  <?php the_content(); ?>
  </div>
```

full ref.:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class